# Chart data label hell

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm running into a rather aggravating issue with a macro that scales the font size in charts. The way the larger tool works is, our company has two different 16x9 templates -- one using 10x5.62 dimensions and one using 13.33x7.5 dimensions. When slides from these two templates are combined, PowerPoint does a lousy job scaling the content.

So the overall tool, which is working great except for this one problem, makes a copy of the active presentation, changes its dimensions to 10x5.62, and then goes through every shape in the presentation and makes position/size and font size exactly 75% of the original presentation. I'm able to assume A/B comparisons between all shapes because the Source and Destination presentations are identical except for the page size.

The one problem is that when the tool is handling charts -- *some* charts (but not all or even most) are reporting an incorrect font size for certain elements. i.e., the size appears to be set to 13.3 in the user interface, but the object model is reporting 18. As a result, when the multiplication of the font size takes place, the new font size is too large. The full tool handles chart titles, axis titles, legend items, and data labels all separately -- but for simplicity's sake, I'm just including the sub that handles chart labels:

```
Sub RefontsizeChartLabels(dChrt As Chart, sChrt As Chart)

On Error GoTo Errhandler

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Dim dSeriesVar As Series
Dim sSeriesVar As Series
Dim dDataLabelsVar As DataLabel
Dim sDataLabelsVar As DataLabel
Dim dPointVar As Point
Dim sPointVar As Point
Dim destRange2 As TextRange2
Dim sourceRange2 As TextRange2

Dim isAutoText As Boolean


For i = 1 To dChrt.SeriesCollection.Count
    Set dSeriesVar = dChrt.SeriesCollection(i)
    Set sSeriesVar = sChrt.SeriesCollection(i)
    For j = 1 To dSeriesVar.Points.Count
        Set dPointVar = dSeriesVar.Points(j)
        Set sPointVar = sSeriesVar.Points(j)
        If dPointVar.HasDataLabel = True Then
            Set sDataLabelsVar = sSeriesVar.DataLabels(j)
            Set dDataLabelsVar = dSeriesVar.DataLabels(j)
            isAutoText = dDataLabelsVar.AutoText
            Set destRange2 = dDataLabelsVar.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange
            Set sourceRange2 = sDataLabelsVar.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange
            RefontsizeChartShapeRange destRange2, sourceRange2
            dDataLabelsVar.AutoText = isAutoText
        End If
    Next
Next

Exit Sub

Errhandler:
    Debug.Print "Error: " & Err.Description

End Sub
```

Just for completeness, you can see that the RefontsizeChartShapeRange sub is doing a simple multiplication operation on the .Font.Size property

```
Public Sub RefontsizeChartShapeRange(destRange2 As TextRange2, sourceRange2 As TextRange2)

Debug.Print "IN_RefontsizeChartShapeRange"
On Error GoTo Errhandler

Dim i As Long

With destRange2.Font
    .Size = sourceRange2.Font.Size * scaleConstant
End With

Exit Sub

Errhandler:
Debug.Print "Error: " & Err.Description

End Sub
```

At first I thought it had something to do with an Autoscale property being set, but messing around with it didn't seem to fix anything. Stepping through the code seems to imply that simply searching for certain chart elements with VBA and/or recording them to variables sets the object model itself out of whack. The business with dDataLabelsVar.AutoText above was a workaround for one issue I was having with the data labels losing their number formatting after changing the font size, but it doesn't fix the issue with the individual labels saying they are 18 points when they appear to be 13.3.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Without samples of the decks that are doing this, it's not really possible to set up an independent test for your case. FWIW, 10"x5.62" is an obsolete size from PowerPoint 2010. Microsoft now builds slide sizes to be 7.5" high with variable width. It might make your situation easier to run a batch conversion on all the old decks so you're only dealing with 13.33"x7.5" going forward.

Comment: After doing some more tests I think I've isolated the issue:

Many formatting properties of the individual chart elements are linked to the .Chart.ChartArea.Font properties. When a property is linked, the object model defaults to size 18 (or whatever is set as default in the xml).

Adjusting the .Chart.ChartArea.Font property is correctly causing the children elements to change size. The problem is that other properties are shifting as well -- the colors and local formatting (bold) gets wiped out when the ChartArea is changed. Also, I can't figure out how to tell if a property is linked.